# Is it possible to cast a quoted string to an integer in awk, while being transparent to non-quoted strings?

Tags: awk, gawk

Suppose a line of my input file looks like this:

```
7162    "cw_107373" 65  65  0.197606944 328.935809057398    "91.67" "11/12" "0.89"  "47/53" 0   N/A Active
```

You'll observe that some of the numerical fields are quoted, and some are not.
I'd like to be able to do numerical comparisons with them, while ignoring the quotes.

For example, I cannot currently do

```
awk "$7 > 90{print}" Input.tsv
```

because $7 is a quoted numerical string

I am aware that I can preprocess the file to remove all the quotes, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution in using awk directly.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to strip the quotes. You can do this using `gsub("\"", "")`. That will affect the whole line. You can specify fields like this: `gsub("\"", "", $7)`